# asterisk chan_sip locking randomly

Tags: asterisk

chan_sip locks causing registration issues with asterisk realtime mysql when displaying the following errors:
chan_sip.c:3821 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission for seqno 1 (Critical Response)
chan_sip.c:3821 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission for seqno 106 
my registrations to my sip providers then timeout with the following errors:
chan_sip.c:13661 sip_reg_timeout:    -- Registration for xxx timed out, trying again

this is not a connectivity issue as restarting asterisk will re-register to the sip providers immediately
the connections eventually re-establish, registrations start registering until the above happens again at a random interval.  Server is a dedicated non natted server.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have debian or ubuntu, turn off res_timing_pthread.so and use res_timing_dahdi.so

That fix such issue.